# JSON not properly formatting

Tags: json, node.js

I am trying to have JSON response after querying. I am doing something like this

```
var result=[];
var reslt={}; 
reslt["result"]="success"
reslt["token"]=accesstoken
result.push(reslt)
JSON.stringify(result)
res.send(result)
console.log(typeof result)
```

console.log shows me an object and i got

```
[1]
0:  {
result: "success"
token: "1f4655e3-bf54-49ca-942a-9e61cdfd8f11"
}
```

but when i try to validate the response on JSONLint it gives me error validating "JSON"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` *returns* the string, so:

```
result = JSON.stringify(result)
res.send(result)
```

or just

```
res.send(JSON.stringify(result))
```

---

Side note: You can simplify that code a fair bit:

```
res.send(JSON.stringify( [ {result: "success", token: accesstoken} ] ));
```

or perhaps for clarity:

```
var result = [ {result: "success", token: accesstoken} ];
res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
```